# Retaining custom CSS parts when editing using CartoDB GUI?

Tags: carto, cartocss

I have set a bunch of zoom-level settings in a cartdb map layer, i change opacity, line thickness, etc.

however, when i go into the web GUI and do something simple like change the colour of a line, it blows away all of the custom CSS code.

Is there any way to continue using the GUI after writing additional CSS lines without having the manually added CSS get stomped on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm afraid that's not possible. I always use a text editor aside to copy & paste.

CartoDB wizards will always overwrite any edits on the CartoCSS because there's not easy way for the software to understand/discriminate what's coming from the wizard from what was wrote by the user. Think on the wizard as a UI for novel or non-experts, but also a source of information and snippets for your convenience if you are going to edit directly the CartoCSS section.

Comment: Simple questions have short answers but ok, I'll give it a spin.